# Count all records based on the last status

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a table that gets a daily dump of all the records. So when I query it i have to add in a most recent date clause so I get the most recent updated data.

I was recently challenged with looking at the historical data to find the number of times a record had a negative balance consecutively.

I can do Row_number to give me the count based on the Balance type and dealer name, but how do I only get the most recent count based on the most current balance type?

```
With CTE
(Select processdate,
case when dealerbalance <'0.00' then 'Negative' 
else 'Positive' end 
as balancetype,
dealername
from Table A
where processdate >= '2019/10/20')
Select * from CTE
```

Here is some sample data from the table:

```
Processdate | Balancetype |Dealername | Balance
2019-10-20      Positive     Luxe        20.00
2019-10-21      Positive     Luxe        20.00
2019-10-22      Negative     Luxe       -40.00
2019-10-23      Negative     Luxe       -40.00
2019-10-20      Positive     Max         15.00 
2019-10-21      Negative     Max        -25.00
2019-10-22      Negative     Max        -25.00
2019-10-23      Positive     Max         10.00
2019-10-20      Negative     main       -80.00
2019-10-21      Negative     Main       -90.00
2019-10-22      Negative     Main       -50.00
2019-10-23      Negative     Main       -100.00
```

I would like my output to be this:

```
Processdate | Balancetype |Dealername | NumberConsecutive | Balance
2019-10-23      Negative     Luxe          2                -40.00
2019-10-23      Positive     Max           1                 10.00
2019-10-23      Negative     Main          4                -100.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
WITH RNKS AS (SELECT *, row_number() OVER(partition by DealerName Order By  ProcessDate Desc) As RN FROM TableA),
     TOPS AS (SELECT * FROM RNKS WHERE RN = 1),
     DUR AS (SELECT * FROM TOPS OUTER APPLY (SELECT count (0) AS X FROM TableA A WHERE 
                                                                    A.processdate <= TOPS.processdate AND 
                                                                    A.DealerName = TOPS.DealerName AND
                                                                    NOT EXISTS (
                                                                    SELECT 0 FROM TABLEA A2 
                                                                          WHERE A2.processdate BETWEEN A.processdate AND TOPS.processdate
                                                                          AND A2.DealerName = TOPS.DealerName   
                                                                          AND A2.BalanceType != TOPS.BalanceType) 
                                            )DQ
            )
    SELECT DUR.processDate,Dur.balanceType, Dur.dealerName, Dur.x as NumberConsecutive FROM DUR;
```

following test bed delivered results looking OK

```
select '2019-10-20' processdate,
       'Positive' BalanceType,
       'Luxe' DealerName,
       '20.00' balance 
            into TableA;


INSERT TableA values ('2019-10-21',      'Positive',     'Luxe',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-20',      'Positive',     'Luxe',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-19',      'Positive',     'Luxe',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-18',      'neg',     'Luxe',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-21',      'Positive',     'main       ',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-20',      'neg',     'main       ',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-19',      'Positive',     'main       ',        20.00),
                     ('2019-10-18',      'neg',     'main       ',        20.00);
```

Comment: This worked!! while validating i noticed that there was a whole month missing between process dates. This caused some discrepancy. this missing data became it's own separate issue.